# How to get images from the user selection in word add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I need to get the text and images that are selected from the word document. I’m able to get the selected text in the document selection change event. For images I can get the count of selected images but couldn't get either the URL of the image or the byte array of the image.

Below is the method I have used

```
void ThisDocument_SelectionChange(object sender, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.SelectionEventArgs e)
    {
        int imageCount = e.Selection.InlineShapes.Count;
        if (imageCount > 0)
        {
            //Error occurred: Collection doesn’t exist
            var img = e.Selection.InlineShapes[0];
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Title" + ss.Title);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Selection.Text))
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("The selection in the document has changed." + e.Selection.Text);
    }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Does `InlineShape.Range.EnhMetaFileBits` help? It's that, or copy to the clipboard then take it from the clipboard in the format you need.

Comment: var inlineShapeObj = e.Selection.InlineShapes[0];
//Above line I'm trying to get the InlineShape from InlineShape collection.But error occured "The requested member of the collection does not exist."
  var imgByte = inlineShapeObj.Range.EnhMetaFileBits;

Comment: Are you sure it's an InlineShape and not a Shape?